# Font Awesome unresponsive to touch in Cordova Android

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, touch, font-awesome

I am using Cordova to build an Android app. Somehow, the symbols displayed with Font Awesome are very unresponsive to touch on an Android phone. I have to touch the symbols many times (3-10 on average) before the event is fired once:

```
<div onclick="share()"><div><i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i></div></div>
```

I tried changing 'onclick' to 'ontouchend' to no avail. The touch events on buttons of the same size in other apps do not have this problem at all.

So how should I make touches on my Font Awesome symbols responsive?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making the div taller, but with a transparent background. I also made sure the z-index was correct.